# Cutting a string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a string.  Sometimes it is longer than 50 characters, sometimes shorter.  If it is longer I want to cut it to 50 (or the nearest '.' after 50 characters if possible.

I currently use `strlen` to check, then copy each character into a new string using the strings array until I reach 50 (in a for loop).  This seems like a bad way to do it and slow.  I have no way to do the up to '.' part so far...

- Is their a better way to cut the string?
- How can one do the '.' part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

//somehow your $text string is set

if(strlen($text) > 50) {

    //this finds the position of the first period after 50 characters
    $period = strpos($text, '.', 50);

    //this gets the characters 0 to the period and stores it in $teaser
    $teaser = substr($text, 0, $period);

}
```

Lets update this to have more secure code, thanks to @Michael_Rose

```
<?php

//somehow your $text string is set
$teaser = $text;
if(mb_strlen($text) > 50) {

    //this finds the position of the first period after 50 characters
    $period = strpos($text, '.', 50);
    //this finds the position of the first space after 50 characters
    //we can use this for a clean break if a '.' isn't found.
    $space = strpos($text, ' ', 50);

    if($period !== false) {
        //this gets the characters 0 to the period and stores it in $teaser
        $teaser = substr($text, 0, $period);
    } elseif($space !== false) {
        //this gets the characters 0 to the next space
        $teaser = substr($text, 0, $space);
    } else {
        //and if all else fails, just break it poorly
        $teaser = substr($text, 0, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested, confirmed working.  I added a +1 on $period position check to include period in output

Comment: Just tested again, doesn't seem to work when string contains no '.', so I added  if ($period==0){
 $period=50;
 }

Comment: or try the second code set, as it functions much better, and creates a better teaser.

Answer (score 3):

First use `strpos` to find the "." after the first 50 chars (like @ohmusama said) but be sure to check the return value and use `mb_strlen`!

```
$teaser = $text;
if (mb_strlen($text) > 50) {
   $period = strpos($text, '.', 50);
   if ($period !== false) {
      $teaser = substr($text, 0, $period);
   } else {
      // try finding a space...
      $space = strpos($text, ' ', 50);
      if ($space !== false) {
         $teaser = substr($text, 0, $space);
      } else {
         $teaser = substr($text, 0, 50);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Good call, I missed that. Should you also just break on the next space (' ') if available? That would be the nicest effect for creating a teaser.

Comment: Why is mb_strlen better than normal strlen please?

Comment: It's concerning unicode... We had a problem in a project where we determined the string length via `strlen` when the text contained symbols like the "ä" it calculated a wrong length.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is get a "sub-string" from your string.

In PHP the function is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

eg. to get first 5 characters

```
echo substr('abcdef', 0, 5); //returns "abcde"
```

The rest of the logic (getting to nearest '.') I leave to you.

Comment: This alone will not do the "nearest ." that the OP wants.

Comment: Do you think it be better to check length, then substr long ones or just substring everything?  About 10% require cutting...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, 
    min(strpos($string, '.') >= 0? strpos($string, '.') : 50, 50));
```

- [strpos documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)